# Saving a System.Drawing.Bitmap to a WinRT StorageFile

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, desktop-bridge

I am having a strange issue where I am able to save a System.Drawing.Bitmap to a StorageFile using WinRT APIs when testing my app, but when the app is installed it does not work.

Here is the code in question.

```cs
StorageFolder historyFolder = await  ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("history", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
StorageFile imageFile = await historyFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

using var stream = new MemoryStream();
image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
byte[] byteArray = stream.ToArray();

using var randomAccessStream = await imageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
using var outputStream = randomAccessStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0);
using var dataWriter = new DataWriter(outputStream);

dataWriter.WriteBytes(byteArray);
await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
dataWriter.DetachStream();
await outputStream.FlushAsync();
```

Any idea why this would fail when installed but work fine when running from VS2022 (debug and release mode)?

I have tried the default Bitmap.Save(directory/stream) but that doesn't work either (fails in the same way).

This is the exception thrown when trying to save the Bitmap:

```
Unhandled exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\40087JoeFinApps.TextGrab_4.1.3.0_x64__kdbpvth5scec4\Text-Grab\history' is denied.
   at System.IO.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(String fullPath, Byte[] securityDescriptor)
   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)
   at Text_Grab.Services.HistoryService.SaveToHistory(HistoryInfo infoFromFullscreenGrab)
   at Text_Grab.Views.FullscreenGrab.RegionClickCanvas_MouseUp(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__128_0(Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

Comment: What do you mean *doesn't work*? Can you provide the specifics?

Comment: Could you please provide more information to help us further check the problem for you? Is there any error prompt?

Comment: @JohnWu do you have any ideas why I would be able to Create, Read, Write, and Delete text files in the Application Data Local StorageFolder, but not Bitmap Images? Is there a special way I need to save images?

Comment: From the trace, it looks like a permissions issue creating the folder, not creating the bitmap image. If you sign on as that user can you create the folder manually?

Comment: @JohnWu I am able to make files in that directory with no permission issues. I could make a new image file using paint and delete it. No permission dialogs or warnings.

Comment: Not to be rude, but are you sure? Cut and paste the entire path exactly `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\40087JoeFinApps.TextGrab_4.1.3.0_x64__kdbpvth5scec4\Text-Grab\history` (don't click through folders to get there). Also make sure you are running under the same identity as the app.

Comment: Thank you for your patience @johnwu you are correct I cannot edit or manipulate that directory. I was testing edit capabilities on the dev folder which works no problem. However now the question arises, if I want to cache some data on a DesktopBridge WPF app, where should I do that?

Comment: That actually looks like the right place (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36550779/2791540)). It looks like you have an unexplained permissions issue. If you can't create the folder interactively as a Windows user then this is not a problem with your program.

Comment: This is getting even more strange. I have a "Store Image" method in my app. It identifies if the app is running packaged or unpackaged. When ran from one part of a packaged app the image saves successfully in this directory: `"C:\Users\josep\AppData\Local\Packages\40087JoeFinApps.TextGrab_kdbpvth5scec4\LocalState"` but when called from a different part of the app the directory is `"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\40087JoeFinApps.TextGrab_4.1.3.0_x64__kdbpvth5scec4\Text-Grab\history"` and throws an exception. I don't know what is going on. More investigation is required.

Answer (score 0):

Because the unpackaged application lacks package identity, it does not support the `Windows.Storage` API.

It is recommended that you use [System.IO.File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=net-6.0) to handle storage in unpackaged app.